# gsl, Multidimensional Minimization

Tags: c++, gsl

I like to use of the gsl library for minimizing two functions.

My functions are `f1 (x, y) = (x-y-2) ^2` and `f2 (x, y) = (x-y) ^2`.

How can I initialize two functions to minimizer of gsl operate on?

Comment: The https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/multimin.html method `gsl_multimin_fminimizer` will always only minimise a single `double`-valued function. Do you mean you want to minimise `f1` and `f2` one by one or simultaneously?

Comment: By the way, note that for the two functions you state, there is not only one minimum point, but a whole straight line of minimal points (x,y). Just 3D-plot the function to see this.